# Проблема с сортировкой записей после UNION'а двух подзапросов

Tags: sql, ms-access

Имеется таблица студентов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо первую половину отсортировать по фамилии в порядке возрастания, вторую - в порядке убывания и объединить все записи в одну таблицу.

Вот первый подзапрос:

```
SELECT Номер_студбилета, Фамилия FROM Студент WHERE Студент.Номер_студбилета<=(SELECT Count(*) FROM Студент)/2
ORDER BY Фамилия;
```

[image: Результат сортировки первой половины]

Вот второй подзапрос:

```
SELECT Номер_студбилета, Фамилия FROM Студент WHERE Студент.Номер_студбилета>(SELECT Count(*) FROM Студент)/2
ORDER BY Фамилия DESC;
```

[image: Сортировка второй половины по уб.]

Но когда я пытаюсь соединить записи в одну таблицу:

```
(SELECT Номер_студбилета, Фамилия FROM Студент WHERE Студент.Номер_студбилета<=(SELECT Count(*) FROM Студент)/2
ORDER BY Фамилия)
UNION 
(SELECT Номер_студбилета, Фамилия FROM Студент WHERE Студент.Номер_студбилета>(SELECT Count(*) FROM Студент)/2
ORDER BY Фамилия DESC);
```

Он просто выводит их в порядке возрастания первичного ключа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом, если убрать скобки вокруг второго подзапроса, 
    ORDER BY Фамилия DESC
Начинает работать на результат UNION:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно сохранить исходную сортировку результатов подзапросов? Буду очень благодарен за абсолютно любые решения, даже самые нерациональные, лишь бы работало.

Comment: В каждый подзапрос добавьте колдонку с номерами строк и колонку с номером запроса (1 для первого, 2 для второго), затем сортируйте UNION сначала по по номерам запроса, затем по сгенерированным номерам строк

Comment: Насчет номеров строк смотрите Q7 [здесь](http://www.sql.ru/faq/faq_topic.aspx?fid=214)

Comment: Если получены номера записей, подзапросы не нужны, требуемую сортировку можно организовать сразу по всему запросу несложным выражением в `order by`.

Comment: Боюсь, без подзапросов не обойтись, т.к. направление сортировки разное, правильные номера сортировки может быть проблематично получить. Но можно попробовать.

Comment: Во проблема! `ORDER BY IIf(row_num <= total_rows/2, row_num, total_rows-row_num+1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте что-то вроде этого

```
(
        SELECT p1.Номер_студбилета
            ,p1.Фамилия
            ,1 AS zpr
            ,(
                SELECT Sum(1)
                FROM Студент AS p
                WHERE p.Фамилия <= p1.Фамилия
                    AND p.Номер_студбилета <= (
                        SELECT Count(*)
                        FROM Студент
                        ) / 2
                ) AS RowN
        FROM Студент AS p1
        WHERE p1.Номер_студбилета <= (
                SELECT Count(*)
                FROM Студент
                ) / 2
        ORDER BY p1.Фамилия
        )

UNION

(
    SELECT p1.Номер_студбилета
        ,p1.Фамилия
        ,2
        ,(
            SELECT Sum(1)
            FROM Студент AS p
            WHERE p.Фамилия >= p1.Фамилия
                AND p.Номер_студбилета > (
                    SELECT Count(*)
                    FROM Студент
                    ) / 2
            ) AS RowN
    FROM Студент AS p1
    WHERE p1.Номер_студбилета > (
            SELECT Count(*)
            FROM Студент
            ) / 2
    ORDER BY p1.Фамилия DESC
    )
ORDER BY zpr
    ,RowN
```

Comment: Спасибо! Всё работает, правда выглядит вся эта конструкция весьма устрашающе

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT top 100 percent Номер_студбилета, Фамилия 
FROM Студент WHERE Студент.Номер_студбилета<=(SELECT Count(*) FROM Студент)/2
ORDER BY Фамилия)
UNION 
(SELECT top 100 percent Номер_студбилета, Фамилия 
FROM Студент WHERE Студент.Номер_студбилета>(SELECT Count(*) FROM Студент)/2
ORDER BY Фамилия DESC);
```

Comment: Тут та же проблема. А чем должен был помочь top 100?