# UNION меняет порядок строк

Tags: mysql

У меня есть запрос:

```
SELECT '%' AS id_terminal
UNION
(SELECT DISTINCT 
  tr.id_terminal AS id_terminal
FROM...
ORDER BY tr.id_terminal ASC);
```

При этом подзапрос из второй части UNION:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      tr.id_terminal AS id_terminal
FROM...
ORDER BY tr.id_terminal ASC
```

возвращает упорядоченные данные, а общий запрос с `UNION` возвращает `'%'` и данные из результата этого запроса, но уже неупорядоченные. А почему `UNION` меняет порядок строк результата? Для `UNION` оптимизатор проводит свою сортировку? И можно ли в этом случае отменить использование этой оптимизации?

Comment: Ну и до кучи https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/757587/221228

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html), для того, чтобы получить сортировку объединённого набора (и/или ограничение по количеству), необходимо все подзапросы обрамить скобками, а сортировку указать за пределами скобок.

```
(
    SELECT '%' AS id_terminal
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT DISTINCT tr.id_terminal AS id_terminal
    FROM ...
)
ORDER BY id_terminal='%' DESC, id_terminal ASC;
```

При объединении наборов записей любой UNION (тем более UNION DISTINCT) имеет полное право начхать на сортировку в подзапросах ради эффективности выполнения операции объединения.

Comment: А для чего добавлена сортировка `ORDER BY id_terminal='%' DESC`? Почему не просто `ORDER BY id_terminal ASC`?

Comment: @Ksenia Судя по начальной формулировке вопроса, запись с `id_terminal='%'` должна быть первой в результирующем наборе. Если оставить просто `ORDER BY id_terminal ASC` - она отсортируется "на общих основаниях", тогда как эта добавка поместит её гарантированно первой. Если это не требуется - мо(ну)жно убрать.